# Header not shown when using scrlayer-scrpage with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, koma-script, polyglossia, arabic

MWEs:

This doesn't work, I only see the main body text.

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic} % \setmainlanguage doesn't change anything
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\chead*{لماذا لا يظهر النص؟} % not shown, the below line doesn't work either
%\chead*{\textenglish{Can you see me?} % no I can't

\begin{document}
أهلا وسهلا % this appears with no problems.
\end{document}
```

However, switching the main language to English and using `\textarabic` works.

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\chead*{\textarabic{لماذا لا يظهر النص؟}}

\begin{document}
\textarabic{أهلا وسهلا}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to keep the main language set to Arabic and use `scrlayer-scrpage`?

EDIT: I'm compiling using `xelatex`.

Comment: What are you compiling with? XeTeX or LuaTeX? The former doesn't ever finish for me - never mind a lost header!

Comment: Have you tried LuaLaTeX? I do get a header in that case. However, I am not sure if it is typesetting it correctly or not. (I'm not sure if it is going is getting set right to left.)

Comment: I'm using XeTex. Included that in the question.

Comment: It seems to work with LuaLaTeX. You might try that.

Comment: How did you get ```polyglossia``` to work with LuaLatex?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with LuaLaTeX? I know some of the multilingual support is better in XeLaTeX, but `polyglossia` is definitely meant to work with both engines.

Comment: Compilation stops because ```bidi``` is asking for ```XeTex```. Before this happens, I do get a warning from ```polyglossia``` saying: ```Package polyglossia Warning: Arabic is not supported with LuaTeX.
(polyglossia)                I will proceed with the compilation, but
(polyglossia)                the output is not guaranteed to be correct
(polyglossia)                and may look very wrong. on input line 6.```

Comment: Perhaps you need to update? What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using TexLive 2015. It's a little bit outdated but I just checked the latest ```bidi``` documentation and it does say it's only for ```XeTeX```. Also, nothing in ```polyglossia``` suggests that Arabic can now be used with ```LuaLaTeX```. I will try to update my distribution and see what happens.

Comment: I don't understand why it compiles for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define  english as `defaultlanguage` in the preamble and then change to arabic with `\resetdefaultlanguage{arabic}`, note that you must include it inside group

**Code**

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\chead*{\textarabic{هذا النص يظهر}} 

\begin{document}
{%
\resetdefaultlanguage{arabic}
 أهلا وسهلا
}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\AtBeginDocument{\begingroup}
\AtEndDocument{\endgroup}

\chead*{\textarabic{هذا النص يظهر}} 

\begin{document}
\resetdefaultlanguage{arabic}

 أهلا وسهلا

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. However, it would still be nice to know why the original MWE is not working. Who's the culprit here? Koma-Script? polyglossia?